# How to have shiny app save gt ouput as an .RFT file on the users browser?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rtf

I have this simple shiny app that takes a user's input and passes it to a gt table.
I also have two buttons that can save the table as an `png` or `rtf`.

The `png` works as intended and downloads the table through the user's browser.

My question is with the `rtf` button. Technically it works, but it saves it to my shiny app's directory and I would like the .rtf file to be downloaded through the users browser like the `png` button.

[image]

Here you can see it saved the `.rtf` file to my shiny apps directory
[image]

Code

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(gt)
library(shinyscreenshot)

data <- datasets::mtcars 
setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]


ui <- navbarPage("Save this to RTF",
                 tabPanel("Table", icon = icon("table"),
                          
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              selectInput("input",
                                          label = "Choose # of cyl",
                                          choices = c("All", data$cyl)),
                              screenshotButton(selector="#table", label = 'Download Png', filename = 'screenshot'),
                              actionButton('downloadData', 'Download RTF')
                            ),
                            
                            mainPanel(
                              gt_output("table")
                            )
                          )
                 )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
reactive_tab  <- reactive({
    d <- data
      if(input$input != "All")
        d <- subset(d, cyl == input$input)
      d 
  })

output$table <- render_gt( 
  reactive_tab() %>% gt()
  )


  observeEvent(input$downloadData,{
    gtsave(reactive_tab() %>% gt(), 
           paste0(Sys.Date(),".rtf"))
  })


}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downloadHandler()` was the solution

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(gt)
library(shinyscreenshot)

data <- datasets::mtcars 
setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]


ui <- navbarPage("Save this to RTF",
                 tabPanel("Table", icon = icon("table"),
                          
                          sidebarLayout(
                            sidebarPanel(
                              selectInput("input",
                                          label = "Choose # of cyl",
                                          choices = c("All", data$cyl)),
                              screenshotButton(selector="#table", label = 'Download Png', filename = 'screenshot'),
                              downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download RTF')
                            ),
                            
                            mainPanel(
                              gt_output("table")
                            )
                          )
                 )
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  reactive_tab  <- reactive({
    d <- data
    if(input$input != "All")
      d <- subset(d, cyl == input$input)
    d 
  })
  
  output$table <- render_gt( 
    reactive_tab() %>% gt()
  )
  
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = paste0("gttable-",Sys.Date(),".rtf"),
    content = function(file){
      gtsave(reactive_tab() %>% gt(),
             file)
    }
  )
  
  # observeEvent(input$downloadData,{
  #   gtsave(reactive_tab() %>% gt(), 
  #          paste0(Sys.Date(),".rtf"))
  # })
  # 
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```